# How to log an event which emits state of the contract in nethereum?

Tags: contract-development, events, logs, nethereum, azure

I am logging a specific event from a specific contract using nethereum. However, my event emits contract state (enum in solidity). My log processor shows 0 events instead of 2.

Solidity code snippet:

```
// event

event Transaction(address from, StateType contractState);

// function

    function submitProof
    (string memory clm_num, string memory lin_typ, string memory lin_st, string memory out_rsrv, string memory tot_paid, string memory date_post) public
    {
        ProofData memory inputTransaction;
        inputTransaction.claim_num = clm_num;
        inputTransaction.line_typ = lin_typ;
        inputTransaction.line_status = lin_st;
        inputTransaction.outstanding_rsrv = out_rsrv;
        inputTransaction.total_paid = tot_paid;
        inputTransaction.date_posted = date_post;
        inputTransaction.isDataPresent = true;

        if (contractState == StateType.ZeroState || contractState == StateType.RetrievedState) {
            cedeData = inputTransaction;
            contractState = StateType.CedeState;
        }
        else {
            if (cedeData.isDataPresent && contractState == StateType.CedeState) {
                verifiedData = inputTransaction;
                if (sha256(abi.encode(cedeData)) == sha256(abi.encode(verifiedData)))
                    contractState = StateType.AuditState;
            }
        }
        emit Transaction(msg.sender, contractState);
    }
```

Nethereum code snippet:

```
// event class

[Event("Transaction")]

        public class Transaction : IEventDTO
        {
            [Parameter("address", "from", 1, false)]
            public string Sender { get; set; }

            [Parameter("int", "contractState", 2, false)]
            public string ContractState { get; set; }
        }
```

// logic to log event

[image: Log event using Nethereum]

The logs show count 0 where I expect count to be 2.
Also how to extract data from log to show that on UI? I couldn't find any extraction logic in Nethereum docs.

Comment: With all due respect, why is the last piece of code given as a screenshot instead of plain text which can be copy/pasted by those who may give you an answer?

Comment: @goodvibration when i was trying to copy the last piece of code, it wasn't getting formatted properly. So I chose to upload a pic instead. Can you help me with the above query?

Comment: You can post a properly-formatted code snippet by using a line of 3 ticks at the beginning and a line of 3 ticks at the end. A tick looks like an "upper comma", and it is typically located at the top-left part of your keyboard.

Comment: @fixanoid need help here

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is you are assuming your `StateType` enum is represented as `int` while by the [solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/abi-spec.html?highlight=enum%20uint8#mapping-solidity-to-abi-types) enums are mapped to the `uint8` type. Consider also the fact that before solidity 0.8 enums could have more than 256 members and were represented by the smallest integer type to cover the whole enum (`uint8`, `uint16`, `uint32`, etc).
So the solution might be to change `int` type to the actual `uint8` type representing your enum:

```
// event class
[Event("Transaction")]
    public class Transaction : IEventDTO
    {
        [Parameter("address", "from", 1, false)]
        public string Sender { get; set; }

        [Parameter("uint8", "contractState", 2, false)]
        public string ContractState { get; set; }
    }
```

---

Quick way to verify you expectations is to look into actual event logs of your contract transaction.
While your original code is trying to find events with the first topic matching:

```
// keccak256("Transaction(address,int)")
0x58b12bad91411401e79e45608965d2150f9ccbea8da6766f587ab47feb89b899
```

the actual event signature should be:

```
// keccak256("Transaction(address,uint8)")
0xcaa7b1db9c296c18bcdecbb504bdabd1cf43c41dac630ab45f5d1f982fce410e
```